# How to set IIS website's default encoding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, encoding, asp-classic

My website is a combination of classic ASP and ASP.NET

My pages' default encoding is currently **ISO-8859-1**.

Even if there's no `<meta>` tag, the response page will be encoded **ISO-8859-1**.

How to change it to **UTF-8**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try adding the header to the HTTP Response Headers list for that site. If none is specified, it will be delivered in whatever the user agent requests, which is likely why you're seeing the ISO-8859-1

"Properties" => "HTTP Headers" => "File Types..." => "New Type...". Put in the extension you want to map, separately for each extension; IIS users will probably want to map .htm, .html,... Then, for Content type, add "text/html;charset=utf-8" (without the quotes; substitute your desired charset for utf-8;

FROM: http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php

Answer (score 7):

The content encoding is set in the `Machine.config` file when the .NET Framework is installed. You can edit this file which will affect the response encoding of all ASP.NET sites, or you can override it on a per-site basis using the `<globalization>` element in each site's `Web.config` file.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: And what about the asp site??

Comment: seems there's no way to set the default charset in global configuration.

Comment: Ironically, the configuration element is <globalization> with a "z" -- i.e., the American spelling.

Comment: According to the MSDN link and its [updated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.100).aspx) counterpart, UTF-8 is already the default.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Server 2019 you can set "Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support". At the moment of writing it's still in beta and I can't find any official documentation. Enabling will most likely do the job.

Control Panel -> Region -> TAB: Administrative -> BUTTON: Change System Locale

You will need to reboot the server after changing this setting.